# How to fix this error "requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, composer-php

i am new to composer, when try to install Bogdaan/viber-bot-php by composer I'm getting this problem "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

here is console output.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\viber-api>composer require bogdaan/viber-bot-php dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package bogdaan/viber-bot-php No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by bogdaan/viber-bot-php[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "bogdaan/viber-bot-php",
    "description": "Php bot interface to work with Viber API",
    "keywords": ["viber", "im", "bot"],
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Novikov Bogdan",
            "email": "hcbogdan@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Viber\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.22"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying install package inside of itself?

Comment: @rob006 i am actually following installation guidelines from here [Github-link](https://github.com/Bogdaan/viber-bot-php). so there is no need to run this command to install

Comment: These instructions are not meant to be run inside of library. I'm guessing that you've cloned this repo - you should not do that. You should run this command inside of your project - it will be installed inside of `vendor` directory as dependency.

Comment: @rob006 thanks for the help. i actually cloned this repo. now i will run this command   inside my project

Comment: I think there is an error in your syntax. Could you try: `composer require bogdaan/viber-bot-php:dev-master` (notice the colon between the package and the version info)